# JQuery - how to add characters to a string of words after counting X amount of spaces

Tags: jquery, html, regex

So I basically need to use split and add "..." after every 10th word, so instead of counting words I thought of counting spaces, so after every 10th space character I would like to add "...", How could that be done with the regex space character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with less code:

```
const text = 'this is some sample text that should be cut after the tenth space character'
let cut_text = text.split(' ').slice(0, 10).join(' ').concat('...')
```

Will return: *this is some sample text that should be cut after...*

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this.

First split your string on space so you will have an array of strings.

```
var arr = str.split(' ');
```

instead of counting spaces you can jump 10 indices in a loop like this.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 10){
   arr.splice(i, 0, '...');
}
```

Now to revert the spacing between the words that was before splitting, Here is an additional line of code.

```
for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i = i+=2){
   arr.splice(i, 0, ' ');
}
```

We know after every index there was a space before splitting.

Then you can combine your arr again by looping through it.

```
var newString = '';

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   newString = newString + arr[i];
}
```

Comment: Hey Umair, thanks! But something appears to be broken, can you please put a fiddle for this?

Comment: Can you provide me some sample data ?

Comment: I have edited the code.  here is a working js fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/umair8794/zcyw0stL/

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need RegEx for such a mission...
Extending @Umair answer for further functionality you can make a function that you can call on every string you need to this thing with, And to specify the number of words and the divider separately

**Function**

```
function insertStrEvery(target, string, count) {

    wordsArr = target.split(' ');

    wordsCount = wordsArr.length;

    for (var i = count; i < wordsCount; i = i+count) {
        wordsArr.splice(i, 0, string);
        console.log(i)
    }
    newString = wordsArr.join(' ');
    return newString;

};
```

**Then You can call it on any DOM element that have text**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    target = $('p').text();
    insertStrEvery(target, '...', 10)
    console.log(insertStrEvery(target, '...', 3));
});
```